# Implement Smokey's !!/alive command

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, random

> ***Note**: [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/blob/master/README.md) is a bot that detects spam and offensive posts on the network and posts alerts to chat.*

## What to implement

Smokey's `!!/alive` command uniformly at random picks one of these messages:

- Yup
- You doubt me?
- Of course
- ... did I miss something?
- plz send teh coffee
- Watching this endless list of new questions never gets boring
- Kinda sorta
- You should totally drop that and use jQuery
- ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
- ... good question

and prints it to the screen.

Your task is to implement that command.

## Rules

Regular code-golf — the shortest answer in bytes wins ;)

*Good luck!*

Comment: Does the italic "*never*" in the 6th response do anything with our programs?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "yes"; what is our program supposed to output in terms of italics?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino sorry, I meant contrary: nothing.

Comment: Is it supposed to take `!!/alive` as input?  Or just do the output?

Comment: @Xcali Just output ;)

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 2](https://python.org), 240 bytes

Hexdump:

```
00000000: efbb bf65 7865 6322 2222 789c 3d4f 3b4e  ...exec"""x.=O;N
00000010: c430 10bd ca53 aa84 221c 8082 1a51 202a  .0...S.."....Q *
00000020: b4d2 4a6b 6f3c 498c 1c8f f18c 414b 0bf7  ..Jko<I.....AK..
00000030: d93b ec55 b808 0348 54a3 d1fb cf95 3754  .;.U...HT.....7T
00000040: 9f83 9db8 15ae 7a75 536a cc8a 69e5 3851  ......zuSj..i.8Q
00000050: dfed 5a71 f731 070f 31d4 bb1d 3704 6e47  ..Zq.1..1...7.nG
00000060: c546 b76e 1c47 8418 7087 2d8a 1865 235d  .F.n.G..p.-..e#]
00000070: 635e fe90 8539 e0a5 9168 e4ec 4a7a 8750  c^...9...h..Jz.P
00000080: 0e50 5a31 f13c 13b9 27af d30f 1fa6 1218  .PZ1.<..'.......
00000090: 98c8 6c52 1405 cfc8 f4f6 2f17 fb5e a962  ..lR....../..^.b
000000a0: 2115 1cd9 3a2e ee61 369f 5685 dce5 bc3f  !...:..a6.V....?
000000b0: f45f 1f9f c3e1 fa72 feed 282b b764 59ac  ._.....r..(+.dY.
000000c0: 3ea5 1342 e562 215e 6163 d184 f0fc d8a8  >..B.b!^ac......
000000d0: 9eba 514a 8ada 77ae 1b86 6f8b b863 c922  ..QJ..w...o..c."
000000e0: 2222 2e64 6563 6f64 6528 227a 6970 2229  "".decode("zip")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZR5b9NAEMX/z6d4GCQKqMPeRykgQNwSpVCQQKJoT4VDTYEiQr98mQ0OEpaTrO2ZX968GW9OP5YXFyWdYX8f08ODRxPu4Kz9OKNlWy/EfOyh9ZyRu7Pwgb@cVgqKD76MBbqaDp1NA4iorVuZpmlNtw9uvZgZkhnFaAEpckVJViOlYJghC4IICjJZCSVUYoZgymuiiX/oENdnhmJGNlXBJJfhui4wMRTIEjq65JWRJkPk7oeOZ19W@08Hge49J5oZmhk16oxWrEXmf4bQJsCapFFlzyg9WmhvDTNu0RtOf3K0ofijmWGYEXvQiDUHSJsafPIWVruEUkKCi40ZgQvCJpXOf77@TPSJwuHMsENHbxU2eYnutYTwgk2U1SBnWVmCMHDNbGp5/40kjZM8nTyeGW54ao1D9q6xCxwajAzwInioyjrk6JXStjLjEZ3QY6JT2uUOXf4wMzwznLYNvUWBYHVEE8kiShfQTGNPk08I3gqgHLOAyJ8lu3tOL2dGYIZoHGATl9El90XqHKF86qiaq5I9OUjF2kAv30vaJ7r615htX@LwNJQAVyzPghGWG8GX3XQH1aVHz6wyRaeGH19f/c2@SXRMeWYkZigpLVtRI3RSDa05Ce1ih3XBohbuSy66A5c4e48oOXo7QHdnRmZGN3ZI5qSiGxeUvGJ7uFcqqDzMNrAxFdbxcSPiO9HODarvtrUUZujGJkptFJplyUqyeCfdmDGe@i56ATeI/bhDdJ/ypeNU/vOjDj9aTrDSsP2pJnjPgyZzcDz6gXUEppWoNn4cPiP6xdkrokLTzGjDj/GOqsaSneV41zcrFfiBH3PqxQiJwDRRbWVV2850/ul0urbgvWCxWK8rdr//2xC2e8Pp70UryxWm@@@OHuLBwZsXR3u4svOrYLdsI65Ni9PfZ8vVidreubj4Aw)

Comment: Impressed, you used a ASCI.-HEX converter and put the HEX to test.hex? Can you outline what and how you did it (maybe you used a tool)?

Comment: PYTHON ?????????

Comment: It should be “plz send teh coffee”, not “please ...” according to the question

Comment: Thanks @cairdcoinheringaahing for letting me know. That's what I get for filching the list from another answer. Should be fixed now. (also saves bytes!)

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 123 bytes

```
Žmõç”¡¸€îååªç€î”#`“Yup
ÿ¬³€á?
Of…£
...ƒ§ Iš§†á?
plzƒ¨ teh™²
ÿ€Œèá‚‡€‚€¢…é†™–ÜÜÀ
ÿŠœa
ÿ‚©§À›Â€Š€ƒ€Å jÿ
¯\_(ÿ)_/¯
...‚¿†ä“¶¡Ω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY5BSsNQEIb37xQBN3UTj@C6q64LQqxQaYvFgHbjagj1AskuVMhrG5NIMKAoRZAHM7wsPcRcJM4wMMz8M9/Pf/8wu1nOh8H/rumLKoYXtHjipKV3KqnEN9F0kcPZNcNuuokNOWzxU2V7aSa3DK94MGEY9ilWwdhbFJtCb/Hdk2h18Dhf8HaPH0IK5VOqyTLkDFZWHZIW92JDjYDyyZDRTgoE8IXPZgpCjg1WBAw/lKhNIa1PNcZzsCJnsLuKRuTOowvsNI4STpMcJTd@o/1rhuEf)

**Note:** *Prints a random response with a trailing newline.*

Golfed using [@KevinCruijssen's well known golf tip.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/96361/tips-for-golfing-in-05ab1e/166851#166851)

### Explanation

```
Žmõç                         # Push the katakana character 'ツ'
”¡¸€îååªç€î”#`               # Push some uncompressible words onto the stack
“...“                        # Then push a compressed string containing the following contents:
  Yup                        # "Yup"
  ÿ¬³ me?                    # "You doubt me?"
  Of…£                       # "Of course"
  ...ƒ§ Iš§†á?               # "... did I miss something?"
  plzƒ¨ teh™²                # "plz send teh coffee"
  ÿ€Œèá‚‡€‚…é†™–ÜÜÀ          # "Watching this endless list of new questions never gets boring"
  ÿŠœa                       # "Kinda sorta"
  ÿ‚©§À›Â€Š€ƒ€Å jQuery       # "You should totally drop that and use jQuery"
  ¯\_(ÿ)_/¯                  # shruggy boy
  ...‚¿†ä                    # "... good question"

¶¡                           # Split the responses into a good ol' list
Ω                            # Randomly pick a response
                             # At the end, yell the response out to STDOUT implicitly
```

---

<sup>Random fact: I was in halfway in the making of this program when my laptop crashed. I had to start coding again. Oh well, at least my answer is winning at the time of writing this!</sup>

Comment: Are the upper lines and Japanese character in the shrug emoji part of 05AB1E's byte set? If not, I think you need to count them as however many bytes 05AB1E's interpreter reads the as (your answer is still winning though!)

Comment: The compressed string for "Watching this endless list of new questions never gets boring" is actually missing the word "new".

Comment: @HyperNeutrino is indeed correct. You can fix this by changing the `ツ` to `ÿ`, and adding a leading `Žmõç`. In addition, you can golf the titlecased words at the start of each sentence (and the `Query`). As well as change the `<space>me` to `€á`. In total including fix: [121 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY5NCwFxEMbv@ym2XLisj@Ds5KyUlyJEFC5Ok/gC6yZq/97WShSRlLZm@jv6EPNF1oymppln5vf09AbVWqueJPbdpTuFDCs0@OTJic60ox0eRdNFDqkKw7I46jsU4wlvKpucU2gw7HHjeJ738TF089ag2AR663fGoh3cYb3J0zVehRTK@nQgw7BgMLL@hz1FwsgTw5yWUiC/NrDzqjKwwAhDAoYXTdQhkPbxNcHMbVPs4KVUTlOcKWfxokmUiDXEViLjA803SpIf).

Comment: Actually [123 bytes](https://tio.run/##FY5BSsNQEIb37xQBN3UTj@C6q64LQqxQaYvFgHbjagj1AskuVMhrG5NIMKAoRZAHM7wsPcRcJM4wMMz8M9/Pf/8wu1nOh8H/rumLKoYXtHjipKV3KqnEN9F0kcPZNcNuuokNOWzxU2V7aSa3DK94MGEY9ilWwdhbFJtCb/Hdk2h18Dhf8HaPH0IK5VOqyTLkDFZWHZIW92JDjYDyyZDRTgoE8IXPZgpCjg1WBAw/lKhNIa1PNcZzsCJnsLuKRuTOowvsNI4STpMcJTd@o/1rhuEf), including a fix for the missing `new` what @sporeball mentioned.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Everything is fixed!

Comment: @SunnyMoon Except for your updated explanation. ;)

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 265 bytes

```r
cat(sample(c('Yup','You doubt me?','Of course','... did I miss something?','please send teh coffee','Watching this endless list of new questions never gets boring','Kinda sorta','You should totally drop that and use jQuery','¯\\_(ツ)_/¯','... good question'),1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9BasNADEWv8ne2Ibj0BF2HLEpXJRAIE49sTxmPnJGmJev2PrlDrpKDODKE7vTRf/pfeVk6p7W4aY5Ud3W1L3O1qfZc4LmcFBO9mX7v0XHJQja3bQsfPLaYggiEJ9IxpGH12REnBKHkoTQa1Pe0Qp9Ou9UEswpsHcnYGETBPRL94FxINHASU9@UMZAKTpwNMn4XkneWldU968nIJVoKq4vxAp95tuNO4Sy7WImvj0L5Yu7b9XA41vffv@b4crs@PxiY/X9m1Wxem2ZZHg)

Comment: [262 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY5BbgIxDEWvYrEhkdBUPQHrqgvUVYOEhMLEMxOUiYfYAbFu78MduEoPMhgWXVr@779f5rn1YtiPU0KDybAUnlIUs9jWyW2pQqB6EBhx7TYdtFQLo2uaBkIM8AFjZAamEWWIuV87rfGMwJgDCA4KdB2i@/bSPgOgMQZ9JlQuRRagDjJe4FSRJVJmvc5YoEdhOFBRyH3GHLxaivjXJB6oJu0n8SldIRSatNgLeLVW1R@/Kparu992u735@/m1@7f77bW6Jwr/rsVq6ZbWrt6tnecH)

Comment: The "please send teh coffee" should be "plz send teh coffee"

Comment: While working on the continuation of this challenge, I noticed that `readLines` gives [even less overhead](https://tio.run/##PY5BbsJADEX3cwovE6kK4gSsUZGqrhASEjIZJ5lqMg5jD4g13Ic7cJUeJDUsurT8338/z3OLWgmOU6QqE/pNSCRV/bGsa7crk9txAc/lqDDSyn110HLJQq5pGvDBwxrGIALCI@kQUr9y1oRCIJQ8KA0GdB2R26K2rwBYTMCekYyLQRS4g0QXOBUSDZzErjNl6EkFjpwNcp8heTRLVnxPkoFLtH5WjPEKPvNkxaiAZi2m//kulK/u@djvD9Xv7V4fFs/He3XP7P9d8/wH)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen the core of the challenge is the KC portion so you should post that yourself!

Comment: @KirillL. same goes to you

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 145 bytes

```
“þkċṁṚFọẏ_ỌƤ:ZfCðƓ$6ṛtẓ2JƇMɼ¤ẆƥyɼȧẒ¡ƇƘ9Ɲŀẏ®ỊH\.ƒgFĊ#Ọṁv;`Ä?ḄƒXƲeȥẹ$Ḟ-Ṿṙ"zḄfWẊkEƓẇẇṢ¶ż²ṘzḄ¢ɼQ2³{Ėṃ"B¡f÷ṅƇ0@bSḟ⁶E⁶ėẇefðRẹȤ»O_33o142+33+197¦12309ỌỴX
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY7PSsNAGMTfpfZWlCYRJXpQlBYRRNSDRYRKIRFswYsI1UuL1UBUhAS0/i0tqd6kVKnZ3dDDbvqRPMbXF4kbmDkNv5k5MWq1epJMG29iXA1vkTSRvBSR3SN9KCO7A2/pwFwXA3CzC0hez5C66iZYW3HAPaQ30K/HQfSF1OFdsKCtw/ukIVH@jczeOJwD57gY2jOySDafLx@J1gr6LXBKMDSiPlKSRf9jFskYyXPmQkbmPlK7WgAXqZWK9PhoEvAhknYa814c7Kj85zJ8RHKVWeNdU/whuQYrv1rZQ78zbY4K0uGThA1TDHblRuRxtl3WtFNlXs1pWk7RF/mnomp5Pf3FfktJ8g8)

Encodes the whole string but replacing the shrug with `!\_(!)_/!` (since `!` doesn't show up in the string and only printable ASCII / newlines are allowed), and then replaces `!` with the upper bar symbol, and then just sets the Japanese character at that index manually.

Then, split by newlines and select a random one.

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 230 bytes

```
Oc"Yup	You doubt me?	Of course	... did I miss something?	plz send teh coffee	Watching this endless list of new questions never gets boring	Kinda sorta	You should totally drop that and use jQuery	¯\_(\u30C4)_/¯	... good question"\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY49TsNAEIXrvcVTqtAYJOhTUCGKKBWKZCnaeMf2ovWO2ZkNMpfKHXIxM6SgfHo/35sXHdd1322OdXZHrghcz4qJdm7fo@NahFzTNAgx4A1TFIHwRDrGPOzcnH4glAOURkv3PZH78Nr9ubCMwMxEVkpRFNwj0ze@KolGzmLqQgUDqeDMxUruPebgDVHU3//IyDXZPqtPaUEoPNuwV3ijViF8HiqVxd2u7Wnb1uen15eH0@Ptej89MId/2qZ16/oL)

Fun fact: If you used a "packed" string, the byte count would jump up to 388.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>283</s> 274 bytes

-9 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)

```python
from random import*
print(choice('Yup,You doubt me?,Of course,... did I miss something?,please send teh coffee,Watching this endless list of new questions never gets boring,Kinda sorta,You should totally drop that and use jQuery,¯\_(ツ)_/¯,... good question'.split(',')))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY87bsMwDIb3noKb7UJwhx4gc9Gh6FQEKBAoFmWpkEVVpBJ4bu@TO@QqPYjLZuhEEPwfH8sqgfLjtvlKC1SbnY64FKpyf1dqzNJPgeKEfbdvxeypgaN2FFhwZ148TNQqoxnHEVx08ARLZAamBSXEPO9MSWgZgTE7EAxq8B7RvFmZ/gSgMgY9JlRfiixAHjKe4bMhS6TMup2wwozCcCRFms1zzM5qSxV7Q@JALWk@iU1pBVepaLAV0H@gaf3Ha8O6muvl/dD/fH0Ph4fr5QY9E7n/qm7kkqL0nemGYdi2Xw)

Comment: Save two bytes: `print(choice('Yup','You doubt me?','Of course','... did I miss something?','please send teh coffee','Watching this endless list of new questions never gets boring','Kinda sorta','You should totally drop that and use jQuery','¯\_(ツ)_/¯','... good question'))`

Comment: And you can save a few more bytes with `'Yup,You ... question'.split(',')`.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>297</s> <s>287</s> <s>285</s> <s>277</s> 265 bytes

-10 bytes by replacing `Math.floor()` with `~~()`

-2 bytes by replacing `~~()` with `|0` thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)

-8 bytes by replacing array with `string.split(',')`

-12 bytes by placing options directly inside of `alert()` and replacing `string.split(',')` with `` string.split`,` ``

```js
alert('Yup,You doubt me?,Of course,... did I miss something?,please send teh coffee,Watching this endless list of new questions never gets boring,Kinda sorta,You should totally drop that and use jQuery,¯\\_(ツ)_/¯,... good question'.split`,`[Math.random()*10|0])
```

Comment: I think `|0` is even shorter than `~~()`.

Comment: `alert(x[Math.random()*x.length|0])`

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>152</s> 151 bytes

```
‽⊞Ｏ⪪”}∧Ｐπ↙!▶�▶τ×Ｂlal⁰FＷ⊕← ″»yε⦃σ$L}⊖0!…Ｒf»V?⌕ΦＹV'∕ⅉ)>ιη¤=▷∧p{<ψ;↶～⌊″≔↔≡m≦ζＸ"´j\`⁹WＳ⌕Ｖ›w}ＬV>ＤＴY(Y⪪h‽ＢＲＶ⌕↥↘⮌\L∨⁰ＭPφFY5^ＩG↑~c‖"⌕ν﹪ηVＥ\`êＶω”A¦¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9LTgMxDIavYmU1I8FwABZVlqiLFligSkhVOvHMBGXiIXaKuob79A69CgcJbhdsLFn@H5/7yeWeXKx1m0OS5sUlT3OzLTxtFsxOKDevSwzSmF1Z7I4KeCoHgRlXdjNATyUz2q7rwAcPTzAHZmCaUaaQxpVdIjpGYEweBCc1DAOifXPSXwWgMgY9RlRfDCxAAyT8gs@CLIES63bEDCMKw4GUcrTrkLzTlizuhsQTlaj5JC7GE/hMiwY7Af0GitZ/PBfMpxvmSOT/w80dGGtanZfz@775/f5p9w@Xs2nb9rHWen@Mfw) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Saved 1 byte by using `A` as a separator. Note: The deverbosifier claims <s>148</s> 147 bytes, but I believe `¯` (like `ツ`) needs to be encoded using 3 bytes in Charcoal. Explanation: Charcoal can only compress strings of printable ASCII, so the shrug is appended separately.

```
    ”...”               Compressed string
   ⪪     ¶              Split on newlines
 ⊞Ｏ        ¯\_(ツ)_/¯    Push literal string
‽                       Random element
                        Implicitly print
```

Comment: "Charcoal" is really really to the point ;D

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 237 bytes

```
`0:*1?";"\"Yup;You doubt me?;Of course;... did I miss something?;plz send teh coffee;Watching this endless list of new questions never gets boring;Kinda sorta;You should totally drop that and use jQuery;¯\\_(ツ)_/¯;... good question";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY49TsNAEIV7TvHkCpAw0LKFa0SBqFAkS2GTHdtL1h6zMwsKLdwnd8hVOIgZUlA@vZ/v7a54tywvN3eXt03lqrZaldmtuCBw2ShGatxjhy2XLOTqukaIAfcYowiER9IhTn3j5vQJoSlAabB01xG5Z6/bPxeWEZiZyEopioI7TPSBt0KikScx9U4ZPalgw9lK7iFOwRsiqz/9kYFLsn1Wn9IeIfNsw17hjVqE8PpUKO/d8dC26/Ofr@@L9fXxcLrcM4d/VuWWs@UX)

If returning a string is acceptable, the leading `` `0: `` and trailing `;` can be elided to save 4 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, <strike>269</strike> <strike>267</strike> <strike>266</strike> 264 bytes

-2: [@user42589](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42589/user42589)

-1: [@nthnchu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98932/nthnchu)

-2: [@Nahuel Fouilleul](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70745/nahuel-fouilleul)

```bash
q=(Yup "You doubt me?" Of\ course "... did I miss something?" "plz send teh coffee" "Watching this endless list of new questions never gets boring" Kinda\ sorta "You should totally drop that and use jQuery" "¯\_(ツ)_/¯" "... good question");echo ${q[RANDOM%10]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BSsNAEIZf5WdRaC9VzyIieBHRohcpRsomO0lWNplkZ1ep4knfp@/QV/FB4kihx5n5/vn@0ko7TePFbJUHmBVnOM5lQkeXBsu6QMU5CsEsFgs473CDzotAuKPU@r5RzAzhA0K9Q6JWA3VNpNsnm6p/AsoJ9BxIg8FLAtfo6R1jJkmee9HpjSIaSoKSo4YMbn3vbKGimOy@mbScg0o42RA2cJEH/W0TrKqzlnx9yBQ3qt5ti/Xs9/tnvj7Zbc2@fMPsDkYzP6eqZRx9js@PV/fXy7vjs9OXr2n6Aw)

Comment: The quotes around `"Yup"` can be removed, saving 2 bytes.

Comment: [264 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY7BSsNAEIZf5WdRaC9VzyIieBHRohcpRsomO0lWNplkZ1ep4knfp@/QV/FB4kihx5n5/vn@0ko7TePFbJUHmBVnOM5lQkeXBsu6QMU5CsEsFgs473CDzotAuKPU@r5RzAzhA0K9Q6JWA3VNpNsnm6p/AsoJ9BxIg8FLAtfo6R1jJkmee9HpjSIaSoKSo4YMbn3vbKGimOy@mbScg0o42RA2cJEH/W0TrKqzlnx9yBQ3qt5ti/Xs9/tnvj7Zbc2@fMPsDkYzP6eqZRx9js@PV/fXy7vjs9OXr2n6Aw)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>294</s> <s>290</s></sup> 289 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to [ErikF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79060/erikf)!!!
Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
*s[]={"Yup","You doubt me?","Of course","... did I miss something?","please send teh coffee","Watching this endless list of new questions never gets boring","Kinda sorta","You should totally drop that and use jQuery","¯\\_(ツ)_/¯","... good question"};f(){puts(s[rand(srand(time(0)))%10]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVBBTsMwELz3FatISDaF0p5DxRlxQJxQ1VaVG29SI8cOXhuoqpzgP/1Dv8JDwqZE9WG1s57ZGbu4rYqi665puZ4fskVqspts4RNon7YRanxg/FxC4VMg5H4ymYA2Gh6hNkRAvsa4M67qeY1FRQiETkPEHYvKEnvRq4pFTwKmEvC1RdZaQxF8CQ4/4T0hReMdMfrAABVGgq0PLGL9k3FasVeIaohHO58su/iorN2DDr7h5SqCYu/EId5eEoY9s0/H1Wojfr9/5ObudBxeUHmvL55Zm5dCHpoUSdAy8AZB5xpNjWIqpbyaTdcybzvj@EuUcUKODiPgU/og@iHnwy@YwzQf2nuYcT8en5GEf/ZZIWR@AWQRGzEbJu2o7f4A)

Straightforward `rand()` selection from an array of strings.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor You should refrain from spamming everyone with links to your newest challenge, we can all see them on the [Questions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions) page.

Comment: ok. I just thought they would find the new question interesting too ;) Didn't mean any spamming.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor It lights up our comment box and that's usually not someone telling us about a new challenge they've posted.

Comment: Ah, ok. But can I keep this question?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Of course you can, deleting all those comments was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>232</s> 228 bytes

```
Yup,You doubt me?,Of course,... did I miss something?,please send teh coffee,Watching this endless list of newqs never gets boring,Kinda sorta,You should totally drop that and use jQuery,¯\_(ツ)_/¯,... goodq
q
 question
?S`,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY4xTsNAEEV7n@KXIK2MOIFrlAKhFFEkpLDJju1F6x17ZxaUGu6TO@QqHMQZ0kwz77//C2nM/nldm32d3Z4rAtejYqLOvfY4cS1Crm1bhBjwgimKQHgiHWMeOjcn8kIQygFKowX6nsjtvJ7@ARgmsGciy6UoCu6R6XsRu19UMJAKjlwMdpuYgzd7UX@fIiPXZF5Wn9IZofBsQq/w1lat9vOtUjm76@X98PD38/t4eLpe7mMH5rA0S4Olkmjk3HTbD7euNw) Explanation: The first two stages replace the empty input with the given string, the second stage saving 4 bytes by deduplicating the substring  `question`, while the last stage splits it on commas and outputs a random element. Note that the byte count has been adjusted for UTF-8 (Retina normally uses ISO-8859-1 if it can, which is why TIO only shows the character count rather than the byte count). Edit: I used @Leo's Retina Kolmogorov golfer to detect the duplication and save 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>278</s> 267 bytes

```scala
print("Yup#You doubt me?#Of course#... did I miss something?#plz send teh coffee#Watching this endless list of new questions never gets boring#Kinda sorta#You should totally drop that and use jQuery#¯\\_(ツ)_/¯#... good question".split("#")((math.random*10)toInt))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9BTsMwEEWvMoo3CYsAJ6hYVghVrFClSpUTTxJXjsd4xkBBrOA@vUOvwkHC0AXL0f/z/v/c22AX6g7YCzxYHwHfBKNjuEvpY0nZR6mrbUlmSwUclU5gxpXZDNBTyYymbVtw3sEaZs8MTDPK5OO4Mim8AysLBCd1DwOiebLS/6mgHgYVA@pT8CxAA0R8heeCLJ4i6/WCGUYUho60yGjufXRWI7LYSx@eqATlk9gQjuAyJQVbAauphREOjwXz0ZxPu92@/vn6bvbX59Ol8kjk/rOqllPwOtRUTV3PVqY2K4Lmq9ubRmgdpWmWz@UX)

- -21 Thanks to [corvus-192](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46901/corvus-192)!

Comment: 267 bytes: `print("Yup#You doubt me?#Of course#... did I miss something?#plz send teh coffee#Watching this endless list of new questions never gets boring#Kinda sorta#You should totally drop that and use jQuery#¯\\_(ツ)_/¯#... good question".split('#')((math.random*10)toInt))`

Comment: Only works in Scala 2.12 though

Comment: Scala 2.13 wont compile this: `error: postfix operator toInt needs to be enabled by making the implicit value scala.language.postfixOps visible.`

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <strike>261</strike> 253 bytes

-8: Change `<?php echo`  to `<?=` ([@nthnchu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98932/nthnchu))

```php
<?=explode(",","Yup,You doubt me?,Of course,... did I miss something?,plz send teh coffee,Watching this endless list of new questions never gets boring,Kinda sorta,You should totally drop that and use jQuery,¯\_(ツ)_/¯,... good question")[rand(0,9)];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5NTsNADIWvYnWVSFZgiwBljVggVqgCVE07TjJoMh7GHqBs4T69Q6/CQYLpAnllvZ/v5Skvy1V/TR85sqdmhXbrmnHNFTzXrcJMPd4NsONahLDrOvDBww3MQQSEZ9IppLHHHD9BKHlQmsw9DET44HT3p4J5BEyMZKEYRIEHSPQOr5VEAyex740KjKQCWy4WwtuQvDNEUXfaIxPXaP2sLsY9@MLZip2CM2oVgpf7SmWPx8PTpvn5@m43Z8fDafHI7P9Rq/axWKI5x4v2@XJZfgE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 150 bytes

```
`Yup|λ⍎ řð me?|Of ⟑ₑ|... ¬⁌ I ɾ⟑ ⟇↜?|plz ¬Ĵ teh ʁƛ|←⍋ λ« ⊛⟑ λ′ of λÞ ∨Œ ∨ſ Ô₂ ℅⁑|ₑ¥ °⊛a|λ⍎ ƛð ∺⁂ ɽ∫ λ⟇ λ¬ λʗ jßø|\¯\\_(`12484C+`)_\\\¯|... ƛ∫ ⟇¹`+\|/℅
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60Yup%7C%CE%BB%E2%8D%8E%20%C5%99%C3%B0%20me%3F%7COf%20%E2%9F%91%E2%82%91%7C...%20%C2%AC%E2%81%8C%20I%20%C9%BE%E2%9F%91%20%E2%9F%87%E2%86%9C%3F%7Cplz%20%C2%AC%C4%B4%20teh%20%CA%81%C6%9B%7C%E2%86%90%E2%8D%8B%20%CE%BB%C2%AB%20%E2%8A%9B%E2%9F%91%20%CE%BB%E2%80%B2%20of%20%CE%BB%C3%9E%20%E2%88%A8%C5%92%20%E2%88%A8%C5%BF%20%C3%94%E2%82%82%20%E2%84%85%E2%81%91%7C%E2%82%91%C2%A5%20%C2%B0%E2%8A%9Ba%7C%CE%BB%E2%8D%8E%20%C6%9B%C3%B0%20%E2%88%BA%E2%81%82%20%C9%BD%E2%88%AB%20%CE%BB%E2%9F%87%20%CE%BB%C2%AC%20%CE%BB%CA%97%20j%C3%9F%C3%B8%7C%5C%C2%AF%5C%5C_%28%6012484C%2B%60%29_%5C%5C%5C%C2%AF%7C...%20%C6%9B%E2%88%AB%20%E2%9F%87%C2%B9%60%2B%5C%7C%2F%E2%84%85&inputs=&header=&footer=)

I decided to use an alternate approach with the new built-ins