# Implement Smokey's !!/coffee command. (Part 2)

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, random

## Like the previous SmokeDetector [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/214077/68942)? This one is for you too ;)

> ***Note**: [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/blob/master/README.md) is a bot that detects spam and offensive posts on the network and posts alerts to chat.*

## What to implement

Smokey's `!!/coffee` command uniformly at random picks one of these words (sorts of coffee):

- Espresso
- Macchiato
- Ristretto
- Americano
- Latte
- Cappuccino
- Mocha
- Affogato
- jQuery

adds it to the message:
"*brews a cup of $COFFEE_SORT for $USERNAME*"

Your task is to implement the function that takes a username as any reasonable input format, randomly (uniformly at random) picks $COFFEE_SORT, and prints to the screen:

> *brews a cup of $COFFEE_SORT for $USERNAME*

## Rules

Regular code-golf — the shortest answer in bytes wins ;)

*Good luck!*

Comment: Have you tried testing this question in the sandbox before?

Comment: @Razetime nope, where's it? (and what is it???) ;)

Comment: If you look to the top right of this (or any code golf se page) you'll see a link to the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges).

Comment: Thanks guys. But it seems to be a decently formulated challange, ain't it?

Comment: I don't understand what are we supposed to *golf* in these 2 challenges.

Comment: @thedefault. what's unclear about them?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor It is unclear what interesting golfing can be done in them. Right now, the most obvious approach is to `implement the function that gets a username as argument, randomly (uniformly at random) picks $COFFEE_SORT and prints to the screen`, and it's really unlikely that someone will ever come up with a better one.

Comment: @thedefault. it is just a kind of fun, isn't it?

Comment: This seems to me like a borderline duplicate to the first challenge. They're basically the same, but this one has "print a string first" and "print the input" added on to it. It's basically a combination of the cat challenge and the first challenge

Comment: I knew jQuery can make coffee, but didn't know if was a sort of coffee..

Comment: @Kaddath it is just a joke ;)

Comment: Yeah my comment was a bit ironic.. Java would have been more logical thought, considering the logo

Comment: @Kaddath Java is not used in the Charcoal Project but jQuery is.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 60 bytes

```
“¦ƘÇ=X⁸ẓÇsŻY»⁶“¢p ɼƁỴŒ?Ọi^gċ{çØLƲ`ẆĿJ$ȮȷẈv&ẋȧ>ċ8½c»ḲX⁶“Ƙa»⁶³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDy47NONxuG/GoccfDXZMPtxcf3R15aPejxm0guUUFCif3HGt8uHvL0Un2D3f3ZMalH@muPrz88AyfY5sSHu5qO7LfS@XEuhPbH@7qKFN7uKv7xHK7I90Wh/YmH9r9cMemCIgxx2Ykgk08tPn///8elQWpRX6ppSVFmXn5AA)

If you write a nilad while there's an argument Jelly just dumps it into STDOUT, which is really nice for this challenge because you don't need to worry about maintaining the list of output characters but rather just dump the outputs piece by piece.

## Explanation

```
“¦ƘÇ=X⁸ẓÇsŻY»⁶“...»ḲX⁶“Ƙa»⁶³  Main Link
“¦ƘÇ=X⁸ẓÇsŻY»                 "brews a cup of coffee for"
             ⁶                " " (dumps previous string to output)
              “...»           compressed string with space-separated coffee types
                   Ḳ          split on spaces
                    X         choose a random value
                     ⁶        " " (dumps the coffee type to output)
                      “Ƙa»    "for" (dumps the space to output)
                          ⁶   " " (dumps "for" to output)
                           ³  get the command line argument (implicit output)
```

It's the same length to compress `" for"` as to place a space and then compress `"for"`. Unfortunately Jelly compressed strings don't seem to support trailing spaces, which unlike most situations actually matters here.

Comment: Could using Jelly's `“` string separator help with the coffee types, or is it shorter to compress with spaces?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing it's 8 bytes longer :(

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>73</s> 72 bytes

Thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) for -1 byte.

```
.•9‰dx$»w¯Ï»Å
0Ž4÷ßû‡Qβ%*mÏaQqîu<´Q™Õj•#™”„ƒoj¡¸”á9ô«Ω“brews aï›€‚ ÿ€‡ ÿ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f71HDIstHDRtSKlQO7S4/tP5w/6Hdh1u5DI7uNTm8/fD8w7sfNSwMPLdJVSv3cH9iYOHhdaU2h7YEPmpZdHhqFlCrMpD1qGHuo4Z5xyblZx1aeGgHkHd4oeXhLYdWn1v5qGFOUlFqebFC4uH1jxp2PWpa86hhlsLh/WDGQiDj///8smIA)

05AB1E does have a rather small dictionary, the only words we use here are `American` and `Query`.

```
.•9‰ ... Õj•q       # compressed alphabet string
                    # "espresso macchiato ristretto latte cappuccino mocha affogato"
#                   # split on spaces
 ™                  # title case each word
  ”„ƒoj¡¸”          # compressed dictionary string "Americanoj Query"
          á         # take the letters
           9ô       # split into groups of 9
             «      # concat both lists
              Ω     # choose a random element
“brews aï›€‚ ÿ€‡ ÿ  # compressed alphabet string
                    # "brews a cup of ÿ for ÿ"
                    # where ÿ is implicitly replaced with
                    # the coffee type and the input
```

[Try it with step-by-step output!](https://tio.run/##fZLNSsNAEIDvfYqh6sWDFPRSUXyGPMImGZutyW7cnVq9LaLnguBFqpLeRLEiBcUiQhY99iH2RWLqpcWm3dPs4Zv55kdq5nMsCljx6jxJYx5wAi7SDu1CHbYb7YP92pYzg6YzL@Hpej7u5kPby8f2stb4/tyxb/bejp3JvMnrxmZie8w7ts@dvXzkuYuBvW6X6DR1IJNUodYYAovTiPlIoElx0ZqVqa2tktOlG4EUoFMWoJ5hUBZawRGnGCFgGgFZEEFXqnAOBmdunbn7uZLtPMvfy19Fjjn7kAfEpWDqbMF/BtiswoMdIVCEECMRKl3FQdOOqvvmgiS0lOykGuQhNCtpgPxxwVwEjMCXFEHMNeklIEwe/oGRlOXIGCgmQpkAxpigmDsKZ/q@wq4GZofOfLjzJ2duwH79Bdk0MP3KCS7bf1HIE/0L)

See [Kevin Cruijssen's tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/64121) to understand how all these different string compression methods work.

Comment: `ðK` can be `á` for -1.

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 80 bytes

```
”↶⌊<σ⪪｜ς∨▶？ρ”‽⪪”>,,↶‽¿#Ｚ\`P➙⮌\`ρL±5⭆À)⧴YQ>δＡτ1¬▶⌈…⌊$h¿ＳÀüτt9Ｗ➙β⁰№LασＵL⧴§⧴”B¦ for Ｓ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BCsIwEETvfkXIqQX9Ak@NeBAsaAve1zVtI202bDaKXx8jgngbZt7wcAJGgjnnEzsvlb6yfUYFClNQNChdb1ffpQN/o6Xqw@wKto@BbYxkWkCcHAiZzkVhKyU1i2WH4MkcQcSaHYSQEF0pWsIJTDMMNH4@93Oy/NJrpY2u659Lq4H4z33wIUkvJY9VoXK@OBTivHnMbw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
”↶⌊<σ⪪｜ς∨▶？ρ”
```

Print compressed string `brews a cup of` .

```
‽⪪”>,,↶‽¿#Ｚ\`P➙⮌\`ρL±5⭆À)⧴YQ>δＡτ1¬▶⌈…⌊$h¿ＳÀüτt9Ｗ➙β⁰№LασＵL⧴§⧴”B
```

Split compressed string `EspressoBMacchiatoBRistrettoBAmericanoBLatteBCappuccinoBMochaBAffogatoBjQuery` on `B` and print a random entry.

```
 for
```

Print literal string  `for` .

```
Ｓ
```

Print the input string.

Comment: Surely there's brownie points for using a language that matches [the name of the team behind SmokeDetector](https://charcoal-se.org/about)?

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>159</s> <s>156</s> 153 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to @Neil

-3 bytes thanks to @ovs

```python
from random import*
print("brews a cup of",choice("Espresso Macchiato Ristretto Americano Latte Cappuccino Mocha Affogato jQuery".split()),"for",input())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBCsJADEX3niLMqpUiotC9iDu70BvEdMZG7CRkUqSnr@3qv/fg6@yD5POyJJMRDHO/Do8q5vudGmevwsvirwACTQqSQkODMMUq3IpaLEWgQ6KB0QWeXNyir3QZozFhFrije4Qrqk5EvIZOaEC4pCTv7fN5TNHmcCj6Za/quglJLDScddp0WZB7zMf21P4B)

Comment: Because `print` takes a list, you can save 3 bytes by using `",` instead of ` "+` etc.

Comment: `"...".split` splits on whitespace if given no argument, so replacing all commas by spaces saves 3 bytes. A lambda function is another 2 bytes shorter: https://tio.run/##FYuxCsJADEB3vyKLXKvg4iY4FHGzgw5OLml6ZyNtcyQp0q@vdXqPBy/P3sl4XNL5tfQ4NC2CnUKj8WuAQFMGSbA1SKIQttQJUyzC1bJGM4EaiTpGF3iwuUZfrRqiMuEocEP3CBfMeSLiNdRCHUKVkrz/z@c@RZ3DwXLPXpTl3jZJZQDFsV3BQxb13ZKVRy9SEZ5MLhrKcvkB

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>111</s> 110 bytes

```
K`EspressOMacchiatORistrettOAmericanOLatte¶CappuccinOMocha¶AffogatOjQuery
O
o¶
@L$`.+
brews a cup of $& for $+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBCsIwEADAe16RQ/BSEPyBRTzZsujBc9dlYyPYhM0G8WN5QD4WnfsIa9jw0PtlOecknDPMSLQGVLiFrMKqML5ZAuEGE6pyqydMqRCFDeZIK7Y6eh@f//G6FpavARNbNcfJLfvBPIQ/2aKlkmz01u2sj2Ld0Ps9kEb5AQ) Explanation: The `` K` `` stage replaces the input with a list of types of coffee, except that a byte is saved by having the next stage expand `O` to `o` followed by a newline. The `` L` ``stage then randomly (`@` is used here as it's a random match that gets selected) selects an element of the list, and `$` tells it to output the phrase, substituting for the selected coffee and original input. Edit: I used @Leo's Retina Kolmogorov golfer to detect the duplication and save a byte.

Answer (score 4):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 150 bytes

```scala
s=>print("brews a cup of "+"Espresso#Macchiato#Ristretto#Americano#Latte#Cappuccino#Mocha#Affogato#jQuery".split("#")((math.random*9)toInt)+" for "+s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc5Na8MwDMbxez6FsC/xCr1vkEIYPQyWQ7uXu6rajUtiGUvZC2OfPXN3Ez8Q/0cIJ1z5dPWkMGBM4L/Up7NAn/NP84EThAd40RLTBbodvKWo0MEq3S5X09aciv8UQKAlAwcwG7OXXLwI2wGJxojK9hhFi9d69bMvkTCxfUZVbx8x54UoVhiYRrR9CHy5/VwPiy/fZit5irVjjWvbGXXcFkxnnu/unfJTUrcxELjUsLg1tOaVa8G45n/elFrXVHyPpHzT3/UP)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-p`), 116 bytes

```perl
@a=(Espresso,Macchiato,Ristretto,Americano,Latte,Cappuccino,Mocha,Affogato,jQuery);s;;brews a cup of $a[9*rand] for
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxCgIxDIDhV@ngoFJHBymCh7h5g67iEGPqVc4mJC3iy1vP7eeDX0jHdWs72M4PJkpm7HtAHBIU9udkRalM1b1IE0Jmf4RSyO9BpCKmCXrGAXwXIz/@z/NUST@LYCHclN7mwGEVx9HN4LJZKuT71UVW11o10i9LSZytreQH)

114 if `$$%9` can be used instead of `9*rand`

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 123 bytes

```bash
a=(Espresso Macchiato Ristretto Americano Latte Cappuccino Mocha Affogato jQuery)
echo brews a cup of ${a[RANDOM%9]} for $1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxCgIxDIDh3afIcIKOjg4ORd2screKQy6ktoKmJC2HiM9ez@3ng39Ei63hbnW0rGwm4JEoJiwCQ7KiXOZyT9ZE@BI4YSkMe8y5EqUZvFBEcCHI/f88@sr6Xi@YosCoPBkgUM0gAboPXgd3Plz8cnv7QhCFbtNaq8b6Aw)

119 if `$$` can be used instead of `$RANDOM`

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>139</s> 137 bytes

```r
cat("brews a cup of",sample(scan(,"",9),1),"for",scan(,""))
Espresso
Macchiato
Ristretto
Americano
Latte
Cappuccino
Mocha
Affogato
jQuery
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYsxDsIwDEX3nKLKlEhZGBkrxEYHuIGxHBpEcWQ7qjh9CBLb03v/S@8IFvxdaNcJJmx14uyTwlZfFBThHZL36RjTISafWUb7yxjdWauQKrsFENcCxu5W1IRs0LyRlLFldwEzcieotSGWIRbGFdycMz9@n@e1kXx6U5L@BQ)

-2 bytes by Dominic van Essen.

Comment: Nice.  I always thought 'readlines' was kinda useless, but now I see that it's actually a pretty golfy way to input a character vector without all the ```","```s.

Comment: ...although, not as golfy as ```scan```, it seems: [137 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYsxDsIwDEX3nKLKlEhZGBkrxEYHuIGxHBpEcWQ7qjh9CBLb03v/S@8IFvxdaNcJJmx14uyTwlZfFBThHZL36RjTISafWUb7yxjdWauQKrsFENcCxu5W1IRs0LyRlLFldwEzcieotSGWIRbGFdycMz9@n@e1kXx6U5L@BQ).

Comment: Oh, indeed, `scan` also has a line limit argument, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 104 bytes

```
%." w#5Gœz,v7‡e´‚?×ÅvNžSÒ",Oc."	y3N.Yí&öPâèq}õÑ6É«’Õ%¯ä=Ä¶/u8ƒµ;AF¢µ“€ä1•¥p.9sNšæãš<KU×Íí"\	z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AZwAY/9weXRo//8lLiIgdx4jNUfCnHosdjfCh2XCtMKCP8OXw4V2TsKeU8OSIixPYy4iCXkTM04uWcOtJsO2UMOiw6hxfcO1w5E2GMOJwqsPwpIHw5Ulwq/DpD3CgRPDhMK2L3U4GsKDwrU7QUbCosK1C8KTEsKAw6QxwpXCpQZwLjlzTsKaw6bDo8KaPEtVw5fDjcOtIlwJev//UGttblE)

Sorry for being rough on packed strings earlier, they help for shorter strings.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>163</s> 148 bytes

-15 bytes thanks to [@Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)

```js
alert(`Brews a cup of ${'Espresso,Macchiato,Ristretto,Americano,Latte,Cappuccino,Mocha,Affogato,jQuery'.split`,`[Math.random()*9|0]} for `+prompt())
```

Comment: [148 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY7BasJQEEX3fsUshCT6DN12EUHFnVnUrZRmmEzMkyTzmDepiPbbU8Xd4XAu3Av@YiT1wVaD1Dxhx2pQAMkQpeO8k/MsqPThJX@gWEPSc/LO0mqrfI2AQGMAaWB@T/YxKMcorkSi1qOJO/poyvakTc/qCQdxBzRjt8MQRiL/FKVQi27TNHJ@bS5fI@styWPovFWuOpVoba441NKn2eLz8fH9B40oVMv3uzTLpukf)

Comment: @Arnauld creative, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 181 bytes

```
@set/ar=%random%%%9
@for %%a in (Espresso.0 Macchiato.1 Ristretto.2 Americano.3 Latte.4 Cappuccino.5 Mocha.6 Affogato.7 jQuery.8)do @if %%~xa==.%r% echo brews a cup of %%~na for %1
```

Explanation: Batch has no array type, so what I do is to loop over a list of strings and print the prefix if the suffix equals a random digit from 0-8. (Randomly choosing from 10 strings would have been slightly golfier.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 76 bytes

```
«ƛṙǐȮ:ȮGɽ≬₅⋎¶∧⊍€ƈ₄β›ɽġΠ↑∷×rv₇ṡḢ18[τ/nḞnε₴ɖ¯«ǐð\j`∞Ǔ`Wṅ⌈℅«⟑ṫrUḊ<↑5ß«$`for`⁰WṄ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C2%AB%C6%9B%E1%B9%99%C7%90%C8%AE%3A%C8%AEG%C9%BD%E2%89%AC%E2%82%85%E2%8B%8E%C2%B6%E2%88%A7%E2%8A%8D%E2%82%AC%C6%88%E2%82%84%CE%B2%E2%80%BA%C9%BD%C4%A1%CE%A0%E2%86%91%E2%88%B7%C3%97rv%E2%82%87%E1%B9%A1%E1%B8%A218%5B%CF%84%2Fn%E1%B8%9En%CE%B5%E2%82%B4%C9%96%C2%AF%C2%AB%C7%90%C3%B0%5Cj%60%E2%88%9E%C7%93%60W%E1%B9%85%E2%8C%88%E2%84%85%C2%AB%E2%9F%91%E1%B9%ABrU%E1%B8%8A%3C%E2%86%915%C3%9F%C2%AB%24%60for%60%E2%81%B0W%E1%B9%84&inputs=Wasif&header=&footer=)

Wanna have a cup of jQuery? :P

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Magic :P, actually first it pushs compressed names of all cofees except jQuery, titlecases them, then adds jQuery to the string, splits string by space, chooses randomly one, push the "brew" string compressed, join it with chosen coffee and Username (input)

Comment: Cool. Nice code-golf lang ;)

Comment: [69 bytes. Nice.](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=ṡ&code=%C2%AB%E2%9F%91%E1%B9%ABrU%E1%B8%8A%3C%E2%86%915%C3%9F%C2%AB%C2%AB%2CMc%E1%B8%9F%E2%88%9E%C4%A1l%E2%8B%8F%E2%88%9E%C2%BECRjw%E1%B9%99%C3%97%E2%96%A1%E1%B8%8B%E1%B9%A0%C2%B2u%E1%B8%9Ee%E2%85%9B%C9%96%E2%88%A7v%2Cc%C3%97%C9%BD%E2%8B%8E%E1%B9%81%E2%88%9A%C2%A5%E1%BA%8B%E2%96%A1%E1%BA%87%C4%8A%E2%82%81%3BX%C2%AB%C7%90%5Cj%E2%80%9B%E2%88%9E%C7%93%2B%2B%E2%8C%88%E2%84%85%E2%80%9B%CE%BB%E2%9F%91%E2%81%B0&inputs=Rick%20Astley&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 176 bytes

```c
*s[]={"Espresso","Macchiato","Ristretto","Americano","Latte","Cappuccino","Mocha","Affogato","jQuery"};f(int*u){printf("brews a cup of %s for %s",s[rand(srand(time(0)))%9],u);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU@xTgMxDN37FVakiqQtUjswoOMGhNjoAGvVIQSnDeolUZyoVNV9@5HkCpQM9vOz/fyibndKDcOMNtv2zJ7JByRybMHWUqm9kbHgN0MxYKz4scNglLQFv8gYMecn6X1SylRy7dRelkGt3W7c/3xNGE6sbzQ3Ns6SOPuQgebsPeCRQIJKHpyGKYF2ISe2oE2Q9oNTjdF0yJdCiOn9dpFE0w95HTppLBeT8wTyy0fDLBGG8Sdd8XVyKcei4DrwueVsrknaKGuOVt4Q4EFna1Xk/7WRy4aKazD2A7@ghWVzgQ@wyng@r5WA0UZ5ZTrlySompnfNb0fz0WHaij/Sp0icsSuGDoier66Y494cEHhq2x/RS7Of9MM3)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 154 bytes

```python
from random import*
print(f"brews a cup of {choice('Espresso Macchiato Ristretto Americano Latte Cappuccino Mocha Affogato jQuery'.split())} for",input())
```

This is basically @aidan0626's code, except I used [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) to optimize the code further. They're so useful!

Comment: python 3.7 and higher I must note

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 94 bytes

```
“¬àews€…ï›€‚ “’¡¾…›o î™Â¶€›o ¹´Ú•ˆÆ€„ „ƒo ¼È¶µ ¦§pÓ—Í«€¸ ›á£áa ÂÆÚƒ€›o ’™”j¡¸”á«ð¡Ω«ð«“€‡ “«s«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY4xCsJAEEWvkgt5iIgpVDBCCtslSLCxiTYGDa5CRDaohYYYxOIPpBE8xFxknSxYzfD/m/k/jPz@MLCW1RYl7YNZxHHJqqArq8atmSceqw003mKIHHp04fmBYlSOEAFP3CljdfgklDgxl7O8TcV60QIVHh4KnKa0YrWmJYxAqIVpSONI2vcopoSyNv2/lEgJYbUbSXItU0BDN@jv2U3T1epY3RWEiWCs7fnjcBIMgh8)

```
“¬àews€…ï›€‚ “                                                                   # push "brews a cup of "
              ’¡¾…›o î™Â¶€›o ¹´Ú•ˆÆ€„ „ƒo ¼È¶µ ¦§pÓ—Í«€¸ ›á£áa ÂÆÚƒ€›o ’™”j¡¸”á« # push "Espresso Macchiato Ristretto Americano Latte Cappuccino Mocha Affogato jQuery"
 ¡                                                                               # split
ð                                                                                # by spaces
   «                                                                             # concatenate top of stack with
  Ω                                                                              # random pick from list (this is $COFFEE_SORT)
         «                                                                       # concatenate top of stack with
    “€‡ “                                                                        # "for "
           «                                                                     # concatenate top of stack with
          s                                                                      # implicit input (this is $USERNAME)
                                                                                 # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 142 bytes

```php
<?="brews a cup of ".explode(",","Espresso,Macchiato,Ristretto,Americano,Latte,Cappuccino,Mocha,Affogato,jQuery")[rand(0,8)]." for ".$argv[1];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY3LCsIwEEV/JQQXLYSiO0FFRNzZhW5LF@N00kQ0E/Lw8fUxcjeHA4frjS9lu9/JW6B3FCAwe8FayI4@/sETNVLVnaIPFCOrHhCNhcTqamMKlCodnhQsgmN1hpRIHcH7jGir6BkNqIPWPP@b@yVT@Mp2COCmZqnW7dhJoTnUvwWE@TWsxk0pxSXj0OQf)

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by [using -F flag and $argn](https://tio.run/##FY2xCgIxEAV/JQSLO4iHpaAih2jlFdqKxbqXXCKaDZsE9eeNkdcMA8MLNpSy3m7kjfUrChCYgyAjZKff4UGjbqSq28fAOkZSAyBaB4nU2cXEOlXqn5odgid1hJS02kEIGdFVMRBaUL0xNP2b@ylr/sj2wuDHZqGW7bWTwhDXvxnw5Fel@GQ92vylkBz5WOaHHw) (and user passed as input instead of argument)